# Showing there is no neighborhood on which a mapping is stable

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions

> Define $G(x, y) = (x^2, y)$ for $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R^2}$. Show that
>   there is no neighborhood $U$ of the point $(0, 0)$ such that the
>   mapping $G : \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is stable.

Here's my definition of stability:

> Let $\mathcal{O}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then the mapping $F
>  : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is *stable* provided that
>   there is some positive number $c$ such that
>
> $$||F(u) - F(v)|| \geq c||u - v|| $$
>
> for all points $u, v$ in $\mathcal{O}$.

I'm not so sure about how to prove the mapping isn't stable. I have the following theorem:

> **Theorem 16.9:** Let $\mathcal{O}$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and suppose $F : \mathcal{O} \rightarrow
>  \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be continuously differentiable. Suppose $x_{\star}$ is
>   a point in $\mathcal{O}$ at which the derivative matrix
>   $DF(x_{\star})$ is invertible. Then there is a neighborhood $U$ of
>   $x_{\star}$ such that $F : U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is stable.

I don't think I can conclude from this theorem alone, since it's not an "if and only if" statement, can I? I don't know if that's how the book wants me to solve it though. You can easily show $DF(0, 0)$ isn't invertible at $(0, 0)$ by calculating the determinant. But is this enough? If not, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Just take x to be very small and consider the points (0,0) and (x,0). You'll see they don't satisfy your definition.

Comment: But I need to show that there is no neighborhood on which it's stable. Not just at a point

Comment: Any neighborhood of 0 must contain 0. It also must contain a point (x,0) for some x $\neq$ 0 because neighborhoods are open. Therfore to be stable on a neighborhood your criterion must hold for at least the points (0,0) and (x,0) for some arbitrarilly small x. Do you get it or do you need a full answer?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am still having trouble getting it. I would really appreciate a full explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume theat there is a neighborhood of $0$, E say, such that your function is stable on E with constant c. As E is open there exists an r > 0 such that $B(0,r) \subseteq E$ therefore for any $0 < x < r$ then $(x,0) \in B(0,r) \subseteq E$

As the functions is stable on E we have that

$x^2  = |(x^2,0)| = |(x^2,0)-(0,0)|\geq c|(x,0)-(0,0)| = cx$

which implies

$x \geq c$ for all $0 < x < r$ which is our required contradiction.

Good luck :)

Comment: In my definition of stability, $||u||$ denotes the norm of a vector, not an absolute value. Does this matter? So here, I believe $||{(x^2, 0)}|| = 0$, which I think no longer gives the contradiction.

Comment: I am talking about the Norm as well I'm just using 1 line instead of 2 for brevity.

Comment: Isn't the norm of any vector with the zero vector equal to zero, though? How did we get $|(x^2, 0)| = x^2?$

Comment: I think you're a bit confused as to what a Norm is. The norm only takes in 1 argument so you can't take a norm of a vector with another vector? In my proof I'm subtracting (0,0) from (x,0) which is just (x,0) and taking the norm of (x,0) which is x. At no point do I take the norm of (0,0) on its own. The source of your confusion may be that |(0,0)| = 0.

Comment: Oops. You're right. Thanks.

Comment: $|(x,y)| = \sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$

Comment: Sorry - why is there a contradiction if $x \geq c$ for all $0 < x < r?$

Comment: let $k$ be the minimium or $r$ and $c$. Then $k/2 < r$ but $k/2 \ngeq c$ so what we derived is not true. Therefore we have a contradiction.

Comment: In general though for things like this in real analysis try to think intuitively about the problems, not just follow the proofs. If you get the intuition first then the proof will follow easily. For example here, the reason we have a contradiction is that we derived that all numbers less than r are greater than c. If you think about a number line you will see this cannot be true.